# Gulp 4 update issue

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am trying to update gulp 3 to 4 and I am getting errors while trying to save both normal and minified js at same time. First of all, it was throwing Error: Received a non-Vinyl object in `dest()`

```js
gulp.task('jstask', gulp.series((done) => {
    return gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('script.app.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
      .pipe(minify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
    done();
  }
));
```

I did some research and changed it to use vinyl-source-stream and I got different error: TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk

```js
gulp.task('jstask', gulp.series((done) => {
    return gulp.src(config.jsPath + '/**/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('script.app.js'))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'))
      .pipe(minify())
      .pipe(source('./js/script.drupal.min.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
    done();
  }
));
```

Any advices?

Comment: Did you try removing the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again? Your original code works fine here.

Comment: @TheDancingCode It works for gulp 3 but not for gulp 4

Comment: Are you using an Alpha version of 4?

Comment: Naa. I am using 4.0.0

Comment: Which package is `minify()` pointing to?

Comment: @Zweihänder gulp-minify

Comment: I believe it's the version of `gulp-minify` you're using. `npm install gulp-minify@3.1.0` and try again.